# Where can I see how much money was spent for a specific Purchase Order on Upwork Enterprise?

Tags: upwork

I use Upwork Enterprise to pay for freelancers. I use Purchase Orders as a means of payment.  Where can I see how much money was spent for a specific Purchase Order on Upwork Enterprise? (e.g., "531 USD was spent in PO 1596 so far").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can view how much money was spent for a specific Purchase Order on https://www.upwork.com/ab/ptc/purchase-orders/report/:

[image]

One may need to get the permission from Upwork or some admin to be able to access that page.

The data is updated on a daily basis.